# Start multiple dependent daemons in one systemd service

Tags: systemd, kerberos

I set up a FreeRADIUS server with a SQL backend running on a remote MariaDB instance. Authentication and traffic encryption should be handled by Kerberos using `k5start` to maintain the tickets. The system runs on a Debian 11 instance.

I created an override for `/etc/systemd/system/freeradius.service`:

```
[Service]
Environment="KRB5CCNAME=/run/freeradius/sql.tkt"
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/k5start -u radius_user -f /etc/freeradius/3.0/freeradius.keytab -o freerad -g freerad -m 600 -H 60 -b -K 30 -L -k /run/freeradius/sql.tkt
```

This basically works. However, since this is a background service it may well happen that `k5start` on one evil day crashes and then after the ticket expired RADIUS will be down.

Another issue of lesser concern is that `k5start` in this case is run as the RADIUS user i.e., the keytab must be readable by the RADIUS user. I like it better to have it as `root:root 0600`.

Of course I could run `k5start` as a service of its own, which has the minor beauty issue that `/run/freeradius` does not necessarily exist, when `k5start` is launched i.e., I have to use yet another directory for the tickets and given `PrivateTmp=true` its probably not in `/tmp`.

So, for my ideal solution the `freeradius.service` would create the `/run/freeradius` directory, then launch something like a `ticket.service` and then resume to start RADIUS. Looks similar to `BindsTo=`, but still somehow different.

Is there a nicer solution to have `systemd` monitor `k5start` and restart it in case it is gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Start multiple dependent daemons in one systemd service

Don't. Systemd explicitly does not support more than one "monitored" process per .service unit. The `k5start` should be a separate service that FreeRADIUS depends on.

> So, for my ideal solution the freeradius.service would create the /run/freeradius directory, then launch something like a ticket.service and then resume to start RADIUS. Looks similar to BindsTo=, but still somehow different.

Pre-create the directory via `tmpfiles.d`, as was common practice before the "RuntimeDirectory=" was added to systemd as a feature.

```
/etc/tmpfiles.d/freeradius.conf
d /run/freeradius 0750 radius radius -
```

Once you have that, you can link the two services using regular `Requires=` and `After=` dependencies:

```ini
[Unit]
Requires=kstart@radius.service
After=kstart@radius.service
```

Note that with recent MIT libkrb5, you don't need a separate task to maintain the keytab – libkrb5 can acquire tickets using a "client keytab" all on its own, if specified via environment variable:

```
radiusd.conf
ENV {
    KRB5_CLIENT_KTNAME = 'FILE:/etc/raddb/radius.keytab'
}
```

...or if the keytab is placed at `FILE:/var/lib/krb5/user/%{euid}/client.keytab` (see `default_client_keytab_name` in krb5.conf(5).)

> Another issue of lesser concern is that k5start in this case is run as the RADIUS user i.e., the keytab must be readable by the RADIUS user. I like it better to have it as root:root 0600.

k5start supports chown'ing the ticket cache to another user using the `-o <user>` option.

An alternative option is to use `gssproxy`, which is like ssh-agent for Kerberos tickets. With gssproxy enabled, radiusd will not need a ticket cache at all – gssproxy will be the one to renew tickets and establish GSS security contexts on behalf of radiusd.

```
/etc/gssproxy/50-radius.conf
[service/ldap]
  mechs = krb5
  cred_store = ccache:/var/lib/gssproxy/clients/krb5cc_%U
  cred_store = client_keytab:/etc/radius.keytab
  cred_usage = initiate
  euid = radius_user
```

```
radiusd.conf
ENV {
    GSS_USE_PROXY = '1'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I tried the favorite solution using KRB5_CLIENT_KTNAME, but it does not seem to work. KRB5_TRACE does not produce a single output then. The kstart@ idea was also promising, but it seems to only work, if all paths and principals are quite standardized. So, I used the gssproxy method, and it works like a charm, once you find out, where to look for logs ...

Comment: If the paths and principals aren't standardized, you can just use kstart@this and kstart@that as completely independent units, with each having the correct paths hardcoded (or maybe set via `Environment=`) – or really you can just call it `kstart-for-radius.service`.